# Problem with order of columns (fields) while loading JSON to BigQuery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am working with google script.

I uploaded CSV format data to BigQuery as new table - the column order was preserved.

Now I am uploading JSON data. I checked via Logger.log that the JSON string is in 'correct' order right before calling

```
let blob = Utilities.newBlob( json, 'application/octet-stream');

  try {
    BigQuery.Jobs.insert(loadJob, projectId, blob);
```

The file uploads ... but the column order is messed up. I know that for querying that does not really matter... but for human previewing the data it would be nice. (neither it is alphabetical)

Comment: Just came across the same problem :-(
Loaded a jsonl from the UI and the columns are all sorter randomly

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the schema to upload with a given order but I was not able to do it. Instead I asked for a specific order of the columns when I query the table.

This will create the schema in some random order

> bigquery.LoadJobConfig(autodetect=True)